# Phonegap/cordova - How to check if physical backbutton exist

Tags: cordova, back-button, exists, smartphone

eventListener("backbuton") permit to override the default action when an user press his physical back button. However, a lot of devices don't get a physical back button, like Iphone, so i have to add it in software for this kind of device

I should ignore this problem and put the software button for every device, but i would avoid to make duplicate buttons

There is nothing on docs, that's weird because this sounds like an essential functionnality for compatibility to me

So, is there a way to check if a physical button exists on the used smartphone for cordova/phonegap (v2.9)?

Comment: Nexus phones have GUI backbutton too, in stead of physical. So I am not sure what the problem is you are facing. It is common practice to have a backbutton in an app and you can bind the system backbutton also (and even change the backbutton behavior). You can also use gestures to trigger a backbutton.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So i hadded my backbutton for every device. It's not a real problem but seems to me as a bad practice for user experience. And i'm astonished there is not a var that should test this. what is gestures?

Comment: I still do not understand what the issue is :-). The backbutton in PhoneGap is the same as the physical one and the same as the backbutton of the Android GUI. Default behavior is the same as the backbutton in a normal browser. You can modify the latter (what should happen when pressed). But if a button exists does not matter US wise. At least,  that is how I see it.